# Redirect 301 static variable lang URLs to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters, static, dns

In the context of a website redesign, I would like to redirect static URLs with `lang` param to static URLs on another domain, using `.htaccess`.
URLs are built like this:

```
www.example.com/first-page/?lang=it  >>  www.example.it/prima-pagina/
www.example.com/first-page/?lang=fr  >>  www.example.fr/premiere-page/

www.example.com/another-page/?lang=it  >>  www.example.it/unaltra-pagina/
www.example.com/another-page/?lang=fr  >>  www.example.fr/autre-page/

www.example.com/folder/last-page/?lang=it  >>  www.example.it/record/ultima-pagina/
www.example.com/folder/last-page/?lang=fr  >>  www.mydomain.fr/dossier/derniere-page/
```

I already tried simple redirects like `RedirectMatch 301` .......
And also more complexe URLs with `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`, both unsuccessfully ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteCond` / `RewriteRule`) in order to match the query string part of the URL.

Since there doesn't appear to be any correlation between the URL-path of the source and target URLs, and these appear to be different for each language, then you will need to do each individually in `.htaccess`.

For example:

> ```
> www.example.com/first-page/?lang=it  >>  www.example.it/prima-pagina/
> www.example.com/first-page/?lang=fr  >>  www.example.fr/premiere-page/
> ```

The following covers just the first two redirects.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(it)
RewriteRule ^first-page/$ http://www.example.%1/prima-pagina/? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(fr)
RewriteRule ^first-page/$ http://www.example.%1/premiere-page/? [R,L]
```

The parenthesised subpattern (eg. `(fr)`) is a capturing group and allows a backreference of the form `%1` to refer to the contents (eg. `fr`) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. If you don't use parentheses then you can't do this.

The `?` on the end of the *substitution* removes the query string from the request.

If these are intended to be permanent redirects then change the `R` to `R=301`, but only once you have confirmed it is working OK. (301s are cached hard by the browser.)

**UPDATE:** If the URL param value does not match the domain TLD then you'll just need to be explicit and name it. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=aa
RewriteRule ^first-page/$ http://www.example.bb/prima-pagina/? [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. It seams that it doesn't work. Nothing happens. I tried with or without "sub-folders", with and withou "(" and ")" around the langu param. I also tried to remove "%1" and replace it by the domaine ext. -- Plus : what can I do if the lang param is not equal to the domain extension ?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files? Is mod_rewrite installed/enabled? Are `.htaccess` files permitted? I've updated my answer with regards to the lang param vs domain ext being different - in this case you'll just need to specify both (no shortcut). Also added a bit more info explaining the regex (ie. `(`, `)` and `%1`).

Comment: Thans again. Yes I already have directives in my `.htaccess`file, which is used for Worpress. I've tried to put your rewrite rules in the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` zone, without success. BUT it seems that the homepages works : `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain .com/? [R=301,L]` but not the internal pages.

Comment: Is the syntax correct for `^first-page/$` ? My URLs to rewrite are like : `http://www.domain .com/our-skills/skill-one/?lang=en`

Comment: These directives would need to go _before_ any existing WordPress directives. For a URL-path like that, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ would be `^our-skills/skill-one/$`